# Recommend way to get angular velocity in degree with siunitx

Tags: spacing, typography, siunitx

The siunitx package has a special macro for setting angles in degrees called like `\ang{42}`, which renders as [image: 42°], i.e. sets no space between the number and the unit as recommended and in contrast to the normal `\unit`, which inserts a thin space. Unfortunately the `\ang` macro has no optional argument adding additional units (as in `\ang{42}[\per\second]`), which leads to the following question:

Having an angular velocity in degree (unit: degree per seconds; I do not want to use rad/s here), what is the recommended way to have a nice (correct) output and what is the recommended way with siunitx?

I have two suggestions:

First

```
\SI{42}{\degree\per\second}
```

resulting in [image] and second

```
\num{42}\si{\degree\per\second}
```

which looks like [image]. Both look unfamiliar, but the output of the latter might look a bit more familiar than the first one, altough the code of the former is nicer than that of the second one.

Does anyone know what is officially correct?

Comment: The degree is a "Non-SI unit accepted for use with the International System of Units" ([The International System of Units](http://www.bipm.org/utils/common/pdf/si_brochure_8_en.pdf), tab 6), so you're officially allowed to use it. There are no examples of the use of the degree symbol with other units in that brochure, but there are books (particularly in astronomy) that use it: No space between quantity and symbol: http://books.google.com/books?id=BAihdjtLZXcC&lpg=PA132, eq. 4.7; thin space between quantity and symbol: http://books.google.ca/books?id=UC_1_804BXgC&lpg=PA60, eq. 5.12. You choose

Comment: @Jake Thanks for the clarification and the links. Interestingly both versions are different than my two suggestions, as they are different between the degree symbol and the following unit. The first source (eq. 4.8) does not seem to have a space between ° and the following unit, whereas the second source uses a lower dot between both.

Comment: Looking at the SI brochure again, it states quite explicitly that "for the unit
symbols for degree, minute, and second for plane angle, (...) no space is left between the numerical value and the unit symbol" (section 5.3.3), so I would say that your second suggestion is more correct. You can type that a little more elegantly using `\SI[number-unit-product={}]{24}{\degree\per\s}`.

Comment: @Jake Thanks again, this is very welcome. Can you collect your comments into an answer? I will not accept it immediately, but this is already a valuable answer.

Comment: Glad it helps already, but experience shows that Joseph Wright will probably come up with a definitive answer once he sees this.

Comment: I had a second look at the SI brochure and are totally confused now. The only thing that is stated clearly (in section 5.3.3) is that a single degree sign is always set without space. Combined with celsius as in °C there is a space before it. So it's not clear if °s^-1 is close to ° or closer to °C.

Comment: The degree symbol is only set without a space if its used to symbolise a plane angle (the sentence might be a bit clearer if they had written "for the unit symbols for degree for plane angle, minute for plane angle, and second for plane angle, (...) no space is left between the numerical value and the unit symbol")

Comment: @Jake, Yes, but is an angular velocity a plane angle? The unit contains a plain angle, but does that mean it is a plain angle? I guess this is a bit undefined, so in the end I have to choose either or.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possibility to keep being flexible would be to redefine `\ang` with an xparse argument signature like the following `{omo}` to add the optional unit in the third argument. This macro then could easily be redefined.

Unfortunately this would either include a call to `\SI` and thus loosing the possibilities of anglular minutes and angular seconds of the original `\ang` macro or include a call to the old `\ang` macro. The latter is to my knowledge not possible without code duplication, as neither the `\let` nor the `\LetLtxMacro` commands can cope with macros defined by xparse (which is the case for `\ang` defined in siunitx).

As a workaround it is possible to use the following definition until there is a better solution:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\angsi}{omom}{%
    \ang[#1]{#2}\si[#3]{#4}%
}
```

Then it is possible to write

```
\angsi{42}{\per\second}
```

or

```
\angsi{1;2;3}{\per\second}
```

and add spacing as `\,` to the macro definition later, if that should be needed.

**Update**:

I contacted Joseph Wright (siunitx package author) and he proposes

```
<num>°\,s^{-1}
```

according to the NIST standard:

```
There is a space between the numerical value and unit symbol, even
when the value is used in an adjectival sense, except in the case
of superscript units for plane angle.
```

So that's the way to go, which can be achieved by

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\angsi}{omom}{%
    \ang[#1]{#2}\,\si[#3]{#4}%
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, load the `siunits` package:

```
\usepackage[Gray,squaren,thinqspace,thinspace]{SIunits}
```

Then this command:

```
\degree\per\second
```

in math mode, will give you:

```
°/s
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This is no answer as the question asks about `siunitx`.

Comment: @TeXnician If the answer is: "Use `siunits` instead of `siunitx`" it is an answer. Whether or not this is a good answer is not another point (and could be declared by up and down votes).

Answer (score 1):

I currently encountered the same problem of typesetting an angular velocity. I used the following style:

```
\SI[per-mode=symbol]{42}{\degree\per\second}
```

Another option should be to use

```
\SI[per-mode=fraction]{42}{\degree\per\second}
```

I don't know if that's the "official" way to go, though.